# Lookup filtered column with empty "Get information from" data source

Tags: sharepoint

I have to maintain a Sharepoint site and I have some lookup column with empty "Get information from" data source in the Site Columns/Edit Column :

[image]

Those Columns fill dropdowns lists with items from a Parameter list filtered by Content Type : Country, Industry, Colors, etc.. But all of those column (used in view/new/edit form) have "empty data source"...

The real problem is that I have to add a category in the Parameter table and add it to a form in a new dropdown but the only choice I have when I add a lookup column is the full parameter list...

How can I create a column like those "empty hidden filtered" existing one ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I finally figure out what's happening : it's a Plumsail Cross-site Lookup with single value field... (The problem is that a lot of functionality are not anymore available with that non standard thing :( )